# clickable tags in posts - Laravel

Tags: laravel, url, routes, tags, hashtag

The code reads the hashtags in the post and saves them in the database.

```
if($post)
    {
        preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $request->get('body'),$tagNames);
        // $tagnames contains an array of results. $tagnames[0] is all matches
        $tagIds = [];
        foreach($tagNames[0] as $tagName)
        {
            //$post->tags()->create(['name'=>$tagName]);
            //Or to take care of avoiding duplication of Tag
            //you could substitute the above line as
            $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tagName]);
            if($tag)
            {
                $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
            }

        }
        $post->tags()->sync($tagIds);
    }
```

Now I want to make the tags in the post clickable. How is that possible? The view from the tag can be called under /tags/id.

Answer (score 2):

Create anchor elements where the href is based on the tag id. Couple examples:

```
// loop the tags
@foreach ($post->tags as $tag)
    <a href="{{ url(sprintf('tags/%d', $tag->id)) }}">I'm a tag link</a>
@endforeach

// or directly access the first one
<a href="{{ url(sprintf('tags/%d', $post->tags->first()->id)) }}">I'm a tag link</a>
```

**Update**

Process the post before sending it to the view, replacing `#username` text with the corresponding tags.

```
$postall = $user->posts()->with('comments')->where('status', 1)->latest()->get();

$postall = $postall->map(function ($post, $key) {
    // $post->tags->pluck('name') is an array of #replaceme strings. example: ['#bill', '#joe', '#sally'] 
    // $links is an array of <a href="..">...</a>

    $links = $post->tags->map(function ($tag, $key) {
        return sprintf('<a href="/tags/%d">%s</a>', $tag->id, $tag->name);
    });
    return str_replace($post->tags->pluck('name'), $links, $post)
});

return return view('profiles.profile', compact('postall', 'followers', 'followings'));
```

Then in your view: `{!! $post !!}`

Be aware of user entered data though, and take any precaution necessary against sql injection.

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea. But the tags should be linked directly in the text not extra to the text. Example:
My name is <a href="tags/id">#tom</a> and not <a href="tags/id">#kevin</a>

Comment: How do you know where a tag is to placed in the text? Do you have a placeholder or some kind of marker indicating where to put a link?

Comment: Tags are marked with a #. As you can see in the code above, all words are saved with a # before the word as tag.

Comment: Are you storing `$request->get('body')` in your database?

Comment: The body is stored in the database in the table "post". And the tags in an extra table with a many-to-may relationship

Comment: Where do i have to insert the code? With this code I send the data to the view: `$postall = $user->posts()->with('comments')->where('status', 1)->latest()->get();` `return view('profiles.profile', compact('postall', 'followers', 'followings'));`

Comment: Should be right before you return from your controller, modified my post.

Comment: thanks, something is wrong with the code. Do I have to adapt the code yet? The variable $ key was not defined? I get the following error message: `Trying to get property of non-object` Exampleview:`@forelse ($postall as $post) @if ($post->type === 1) {{$post->body}} @elseif ........ @endforelse`